# Maximising an Integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization

I do not understand why I cannot maximise the following integral by changing `v`

```
rrrintegral[egap_?NumericQ, v_?NumericQ] := 
  Module[{}, 
   NIntegrate[energy^2/(Exp[(energy - v)] - 1), {energy, egap, 10}]];

Maximize[{v*rrrintegral[1, v], v > 0}, v]
```

I get the following error:

> The integrand has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling
>   points in the region with boundaries

I have tried using "`?NumericQ`" but with no luck.

Comment: I get no error, but `Maximize` does not evaluate.  `Maximize` is a symbolic solver, which requires a symbolic expression it can analyze.  I think you need a numeric solver, such as `FindMaximum` or `NMaximize`.  (But you also need to do something about the singularity in the integral as `energy == v`. Maybe `Method -> "PrincipalValue"`?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps use [`FindMaximum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMaximum.html) or [`NMaximize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMaximize.html)?

There's a singularity in the integrand when `egap < v < 10` that needs to be addressed.  My guess is `Method -> "PrincipalValue"` is what is intended.  For that method, one needs to specify the singular points in the iterator: `{energy, egap, v, 10}`.

```
rrrintegral[egap_?NumericQ, v_?NumericQ] := If[egap < v < 10,
   NIntegrate[energy^2/(Exp[(energy - v)] - 1), {energy, egap, v, 10},
     Method -> "PrincipalValue"],
   NIntegrate[energy^2/(Exp[(energy - v)] - 1), {energy, egap, 10}]];

NMaximize[{v*rrrintegral[1, v], v > 0}, v]
(*  {33.4991, {v -> 3.12388}}  *)
```

Check the big picture (or do this first and use `FindMaximum`, which head-to-head is usually faster than `NMaximize`):

```
Plot[{v*rrrintegral[1, v]}, {v, 0, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 6):

Quite a straightforward approch would be evaluating the integral symbolically, and then maximizing the appropriate function. Using `Assumptions` we can restrict the integral to an appropriate domain, e.g. (it takes a bit to evaluate):

```
Integrate[ energy^2/(Exp[(energy - v)] - 1), {energy, egap, 10}, 
           Assumptions -> 10 > egap > v > 0]
```

> ```
> 1/3 (-1000 + egap^3 - 3 I egap^2 Pi + 300 Log[1 - E^(10 - v)] - 
>   3 egap^2 Log[-1 + E^(egap - v)] + 60 PolyLog[2, E^(10 - v)] - 
>   6 egap PolyLog[2, E^(egap - v)] - 6 PolyLog[3, E^(10 - v)] + 
>   6 PolyLog[3, E^(egap - v)])
> ```

Next we define

```
Int[egap_, v_] := 1/3 (-1000 + egap^3 + 300 Log[1 - E^(10 - v)] 
    -3 egap^2 Log[1 - E^(egap - v)] + 60 PolyLog[2, E^(10 - v)] 
    -6 egap PolyLog[2, E^(egap - v)] - 6 PolyLog[3, E^(10 - v)] 
    +6 PolyLog[3, E^(egap - v)])
```

Existing complex expression in the integral doesn't hurt since we can get rid off by changing the sign under `Log`. I have to use `Re` because of very small imaginary perturbations being a numerical artefact.

```
NMaximize[{v Int[1, v] // Re, 10 > v > 0}, v]
```

> ```
> {33.4991, {v -> 3.12388}}
> ```

Comment: Actually, there may be a problem with both our answers: Doesn't the integral go to `Infinity` as `v` goes to `1` (if `egap = 1`)?  So, no max., unless there are further restrictions on `v`?

Comment: It seems you are right, however If I replace my approach by e.g. `NMaximize[{v Int[1, v] // Re, 10 > v > 1.1}, v]` it'll be correct.

Comment: Yes, that's the sort of restriction I was thinking of.

Comment: I have checked that something like `v > 1000000000001/1000000000000` is sufficient.

Comment: The unsatisfactory part of this closed form approach is the presence of terms of the form `PolyLog[k, Exp[u]]`; this is just asking for numerical trouble. Unfortunately, Bose-Einstein or Fermi-Dirac functions aren't yet built-in, so this will have to do.